# Python, Function containing imports

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a function that contains all my imports statement, :

```
def imports():
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    etc...
```

save it in a .py file as a module and call that function from my Jupyter Notebook.
This is simply to unclutter the Notebook. However it seems it doesnt work to create a function containing import statements? (I'm receiving errors `NameError: name 'pd' is not defined` ). Anyone knows why?

Comment: `import pandas as pd` creates a variable `pd`. In your case, the variable is local to the function and not visible outside.

Comment: @DYZ Is there a way around that? Maybe declare the `as...` as global?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead, put into your module all the import statements you want and as you'd normally put them

`contents_of_your_module.py`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
import seaborn as sns
```

---

Then you import from Jupyter

```
from contents_of_your_module import *
```

---

Or, you can create a namespace for your module and do this

```
import contents_of_you_module as radar
```

And then you can access all the modules via your name space

```
radar.pd.DataFrame
```

Comment: Great answers and very informative as usual. However I think the solution of DYZ is more what I am after. But thx!

Comment: @Radar glad I could help.  DYZ provided a great answer.

Answer (score 3):

`import pandas as pd` creates a variable `pd`. In your case, the variable is local to the function and not visible outside. Declare the shortcuts to the imported modules as global variables:

```
def imports():
    global pd, np
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
```

Comment: Is there any draw to declaring the variables as global? I.e. in term of performances etc? Otherwise I think this is what i was after.

Comment: You will have them as global, anyway, just by virtue of `import`ing `as`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I would say that it's a very bad practice to do what you want to do. If you want to do exactly what you describe you can't do it in a pythonic way.

But this is a solution that probably would work:

Pretend you have a module called `imports.py`, that should handle all your imports:

File: **imports.py:**

`import numpy as np
import pandas as pd`

The you can have a function in your program.

`def do_funky_import_from():
   from imports import *`